# Configuring source repository in my pom.xml file

Tags: maven

On my project, i use MVN site tool to generate the project site. Now i see an entry for a Source Repository which is off course blank. How can i configure my pom.xml for this ? Can i use maven to commit directly to git ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [SCM tag](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#SCM) in the pom like this:

```
  <scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:khmarbaise/sapm.git</developerConnection>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/khmarbaise/sapm.git</connection>
    <url>https://github.com/khmarbaise/sapm</url>
  </scm>
```

Comment: And then check the [maven scm plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/) to see what you can do with that

Comment: Can this be used with GIT ?